# How to properly find for duplicates and deleted them

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query but at some point my logic is wrong and I am having problems finding out why its not deleting / selecting the right data.

***The Question I need to ask is:***
How can I delete duplicates `resource_type=2`  FROM `user_address` and keep the original `resource_type=2`.

I've created the following queries. **The problem** when I test my final query and check some of the results some of them don't have a repeated `resource_type=2`, this shouldnt be there. I cant find the logic problem to my query.

Can anyone spot the problem?

This `Query` gives me `602` results When trying to find who has duplicates. Thus I've 602 `user_address` that are unique aparently

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM user_address 
WHERE resource_type=2  
GROUP BY member_num 
HAVING COUNT(resource_type) > 1
```

If i do the following query i get `7420` results

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM user_address 
WHERE resource_type=2
```

When I do the Select query to check what would be deleted I get `6,818` results

```
SELECT * FROM user_address 
    WHERE id NOT IN 
    (select * from 
        (SELECT MIN(id)
            FROM user_address 
            WHERE resource_type=2  
            GROUP BY member_num 
            HAVING COUNT(resource_type) > 1
        ) as t) AND resource_type <> 1 AND resource_type <> 3 AND resource_type <> 4
```

Comment: What is the criteria for original duplicate?

Comment: @Mihai I just want to check if there is more than one address with  `resource_type=2` if there is then delete all the rest that have `resource_type=2` but are duplicated but keep the lowest ID (first id). also minding not to delete those that have id 1, 3 or 4

Comment: 7420 - 602 = 6818, where is the problem?

Comment: @WillP. the problem is that when i check the final select statement some of the results dont have a repeated `resource_type=2` thus shouldnt be there

Answer (score 0):

These all make sense.

You have 602 values that are duplicates according to your definition (`resource_type = 2` on more than one row).

You have 7,420 *rows* that have `resource_type = 2`.

You have 6,818 rows that meet whatever conditions are in your final query.  It may be a coincidence that 602 + 6,818 = 7,420.

I think the query you want is more like:

```
delete ua from user_addresses ua join
               (SELECT MIN(id) as minid, member_num
                FROM user_address 
                WHERE resource_type=2  
                GROUP BY member_num 
                HAVING COUNT(resource_type) > 1
               ) tokeep
               on ua.member_num = tokeep.member_num and
                  ua.id > tokeep.minid;
```

I don't know what the additional conditions are for in the final `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no nulls, you GROUP BY the unique columns, and SELECT the MIN (or MAX) RowId as the row to keep.

this answer looks useful :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949/367006